# Spring Multi-Tenancy - Adding new tenant without restart (using AbstractRoutingDataSource)

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, spring-data, multi-tenant

I'm implementing a multi-tenant system using Spring where each tenant has its own database. I have everything up and running.

I've extended "AbstractRoutingDataSource" and overridden "determineCurrentLookupKey" to determine which connection to use via the users domain/tenancy.

The "AbstractRoutingDataSource" is instantiated when the app loads and all the possible database connections are set there.

Here's my question -

Is there a way of dynamically adding additional connections to the AbstractRoutingDataSource? I want to be able to add additional tenants without restarting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Not with the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`. We used/developed [this](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/) about 10 years ago, still works like charm in production. It is actually more flexible then just a datasource (we used it for messaging, theming, properties etc.).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum it was a lot more straight forward than I thought. The AbstractRoutingDataSource class threw me a curve ball. Following your example I've managed to get things up and running using the AbstractDataSource class instead.Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

I am too late to this thread, but recently I needed to build a Saas style multi-tenant web app. Tenants needed to be added dynamically without requiring a server restart. So I shared my learnings [here](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/05/adding-tenants-without-application.html) with a complete working example.

Comment: I read you blog, I benefit a lot, but I want to know what is the difference between implementing AbstractRoutingDataSource  and implementation the 2 hibernate interfaces ?

Comment: @ehabrefaat `AbstractRoutingDataSource` has been around in Spring since a very long time. Please check this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/).  `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` is a [Hibernate feature](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver.html) and I used it as Spring JPA uses HIbernate under the hood by default.

Answer (score 2):

Yes You can do So, Here is complete project which explains very nicely about your requirement:
[Multi-tenancy: Managing multiple datasources with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759672/multi-tenancy-managing-multiple-datasources-with-spring-data-jpa/)