# One Repository for different datasources

Tags: java, spring-data, datasource

I want to have just **one implementation of repository** class **for multiple datasources**.

Imagine that there is 1 application for multiple countries (with their dbs) and all repositories are the same for all of those countries..

---

**Basic structure** looks like this:

```
org.company.name
                .config.{country-shortcut}Config
                .repository.{country-shortcut}.SameRepository{country-shortcut}
                .. other parts ..
```

**Repository class** could look like this:

```
package org.company.name.repository.{country-shortcut}.SomethingRepository 

public class SomethingRepository extends CrudRepository<Something, Long> {
    ... some methods ...
}
```

---

Let's now look at some implementation.. We take UK as a our country now..

**Country repository** class for some country..

```
package org.company.name.repository.uk.SomethingRepositoryUk

public class SomethingRepositoryUk extends SomethingRepository {}
```

**Basic config** for each datasource.. I have multiple configs (one for each country)..

```
package org.company.name.config.UkConfig

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryUK",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerUK",
        basePackages = {"org.company.name.repository.uk"})
public class UkConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "dataSourceUk")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ... datasource settings (url, user, pass, etc.)  ...
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryUk")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSourceUk") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("org.company.name.repository.model")
                .persistenceUnit("uk")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerUk")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactoryUk") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

---

Config is fine by me, but is it possible to do not have multiple repositories (each for country, everything the same..)? It's bothering me because it seems like an unclean implementation..

Comment: If you plan to work with multiply datasources IMO it's better to use another approach - so called 'multitenancy'. Hope my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783853) and the related [project](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo) will be helpful...

Comment: That seems like really interesting approach.. I will have a look on that! :) Thanks