# Springboot + Spring data same entity in multiple databases

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, datasource

I have a table "config" in multiple databases (for countries "uk", "pl", ...) and I want to load this table for each DB with Springboot and Spring data. So at the start of application I want to load config tables from each database in to one collection.

I looked into using AbstractRoutingDatasource but I feel like it is no ideal.

What approach would you recommend?

Comment: You should use a multitenancy approach. Please find my recommendation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783853/5380322)...

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks!

Comment: If you like some answer don't forget to upvote it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use below example for my code there are one DB declare as primary. [link](https://medium.com/@paulushc/multi-database-application-with-spring-boot-777aaf5a1e4e) or [link2](https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7) there second one is easy to understand.