# How to connect database with configuration stored in main database at run time in Spring Boot?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I have a requirement where I have one main DB which contains the configuration of different clients DB connections. When I post the Data using Rest API containing JWT then that token will contain the client name and based on client name, I have to fetch the client DB Configurations from Main DB and do the DB connection and insert the data into that DB.

I have gone through various posts around it but not able to find any concrete example.

Currently I am using Spring Boot with Data JPA in project. If anyone has any solution with Spring JDBC Template, I am ready to move my application into that.

Comment: The correct direction is use `Multi-tenant` then create your own custom `Multitenant Connection Provider` in order to provide/switch the chosen `datasource`.

Comment: Basically it's kind of multi-tenant architecture where we get data from multiple sources/ clients and we have to store data on the basis of tenant or client (their own schema).  You can fetch information from the database (master DB) and create a connection on your own and keep that in connection pool with a map, tenant as key. When you have to insert data you can fetch connection from Map and insert data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jonathan Johx has mentioned its a multi tenant application, each tenant has its schema.
To provide some concrete directions, You can create a special data source that will act as a proxy for real data sources, each of those can be in charge for 1 schema connection.

Spring already provides [AbstractRoutingDatSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) for this purpose or you can roll your own. Basically you should define some mapping method ([determineCurrentLookupKey](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html#determineCurrentLookupKey--)) and maintain the map of key to actual data source that can be updated in real time in case a new data source should be connected.

I've found [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759672/multi-tenancy-managing-multiple-datasources-with-spring-data-jpa) that explains this approach more in-depth, so no reason to duplicate this information.

Some points to consider based on your question:

- Sometimes new data sources should be registered in runtime
- Probably it worth to close connections and free up the resources both on your application side and RDBMS side by closing the data source upon some ttl if no-one uses it.
- Since you've mentioned spring boot, it might have an actuator health check that checks the database connectivity, so make sure it still answers the requirements. I mention this because if it will respond with non-200 code and you're running in some advanced environment that makes health-checks like this (like kubernetes, ecs and so forth), the microservice might not be considered healthy because of this, so your devops might be angry :)

Comment: `This is answer is useful` upvoted :) thanks for the mention.

Comment: Thanks Mark Bramnik for giving the hints and example post. https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo example really helped to achieve the functionality.