# spring boot multitenant from database and not from properties

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I want to load multitenant database from a database not from properties file. I am following this tutorial (https://fizzylogic.nl/2016/01/24/make-your-spring-boot-application-multi-tenant-aware-in-2-steps/). 
This is how my DataSource Bean looks like:

```
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Map<Object, Object> resolvedDataSources = this.multiTenantDbBuilder.getResolvedDataSources();
        TenantAwareRoutingSource dataSource = new TenantAwareRoutingSource();
        dataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(this.defaultDataSource());
        dataSource.setTargetDataSources(resolvedDataSources);
        dataSource.afterPropertiesSet(); // Call this to finalize the initialization of the data source.
        return dataSource;
    }
```

I would like to retrieve my resolvedDataSources  from a database (the default one), the problem is that i am not able to use JPA because DataSource bean has not been created already.

Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

Such an implementation is a bit complicated than it seemed at first glance - It's neccesary to create two datasources: one for AbstractRoutingDataSource (a 'multi-database' datasource), the second - for the database where the tenant properties are stored ([in this style](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)).

You can find the working example in this branch of my demo project: [tenant-in-db](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo/tree/tenant-in-db).

To run the branch - first start Postgres with [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo/blob/tenant-in-db/docker-compose.yml) - it creates predefined tenant DBs, then run [Application](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo/blob/tenant-in-db/service/src/main/java/io/github/cepr0/demo/Application.java). After that you will be able to run demo requests in [api-demo.http](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-multitenant-db-demo/blob/tenant-in-db/api-demo.http) (if you are using IntelliJ IDEA).

---

My original post about [multi-tenancy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49783853/5380322).