# Multiple Datasources with single JPA Repository type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 databases with identical schemas, but for 2 different markets (let's say `us-db` and `eu-db`). Since the schemas are identical, I can use the same entity classes - the `publisher` table is the same in both databases, so I only need 1 `Publisher` class. It follows, that I only need a single Repo:

```java
@Repository
public interface PublisherRepository extends CrudRepository<Publisher, Long> {
}
```

However, I would like to set it up so that my Spring Context contains 2 Beans of type `PublisherRepository` - one where the underlying datasource is `us-db`, and the other - `eu-db`.

Is it possible to achieve this? I'm also open to other implementation suggestions that eliminate the need for duplication of entity definitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-tenancy: Managing multiple datasources with Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759672/multi-tenancy-managing-multiple-datasources-with-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: Yes! This looks like it would do the trick! Definitely more complex than what I had hoped for, but not sure if there are other options. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Spring (Boot) don't support multiple data-source out-of-the-box.** You can use trick like this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases . I believe that, If Spring did not support multiple datasources out-of-the-box, your try is not good practice.

I think best practices is, using single datasource, but use 2 micro-services.

Or sometime switching environment `application.properties` file will be helpful to you.

Comment: Configuring multiple datasources is not enough unfortunately. I require the additional step of somehow "binding" them to instances of PublisherRepository.

Comment: You can use 2 microservices, no problem. Don't care about repository layer, care about persisting layer first. Then control what you want in Controller. I am program Java server side 8 years, believe me.

Comment: I agree that, this would probably be best practice. The component I'm working on receives data from an SNS/SQL bound to a replication slot of a single DB. I would like to try to solve this problem inside this component before changing the architecture.

Comment: Yes, control it by controller, not by repository. If has 2 data sources, use 2 microservices.

Comment: this got me thinking about whether I should implement 2 microservices instead of one

Comment: What if the other database is just a cache?